# Too few arguments to function while arguments count is correct

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

There was a question like this a year ago, and it was never answered.  Instead of asking a new question on an old thread, I am going to open a new question.  Anyways, on to the question.


When compiling the Zen kernel for Linux, I came across this error while `make-kpkg`ing the kernel source:

```
arch/x86/platform/intel-mid/early_printk_intel_mid.c: In function ‘dw_kmsg_dump’:
arch/x86/platform/intel-mid/early_printk_intel_mid.c:121:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘early_mrst_console.write’
   early_mrst_console.write(&early_mrst_console, line, len);
```

Here's the code for early_mrst_console.write (early_mrst_console is a `struct`, by the way, with a link to the function `early_mrst_spi_write` for its `write` function):

```
static void early_mrst_spi_write(struct console *con, const char *str,
                    unsigned n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n && *str; i++) {
        if (*str == '\n')
            early_mrst_spi_putc('\r');
        early_mrst_spi_putc(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not a C expert (not even an amateur, really), but it looks like that `early_mrst_spi_write` takes 3 arguments, and the call to it gives 3 arguments.  Why is it calling an error, and how can I change it to fix the problem?

EDIT: As per request, the `struct`:

```
struct console early_mrst_console = {
    .name =     "earlymrst",
    .write =    early_mrst_spi_write,
    .flags =    CON_PRINTBUFFER,
    .index =    -1,
};
```

Comment: Cannot correlate code and error message. Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: @Deduplicator I believe I have.  It's an error message in the first snippet, a call to `early_mrst_console.write` failing.  `early_mrst_console` is a struct, and its function `write` is a reference to the function in the second snippet.  Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Show us the code that links the `.write` member to this function.  My guess is that the `con` argument is being passed automagically, and you only need to provide 2 arguments.

Comment: Maybe you have `#include`s missing, or out of order (really order shouldn't matter).

Comment: Confirm `struct console` is defined prior to `dw_kmsg_dump()`.  Missing include?

Comment: @chux the struct console is defined after `dw_kmsg_dump()`.  I don't know if I have missing includes; this isn't my code and I have barely any knowledge of C.  Should I copy-paste the `struct console` before `dw_kmsg_dump()`?

Answer (score 1):

Give us the definition of "struct console". I guess it's write requires more parameters.

Some compilers might not give warnings about assignment of function of incompatible type depending on it's settings.

In any case when deciding if the number and types of arguments is correct, the compiler will only look at what it says in struct console and would not care about how you declare early_mrst_spi_write (this might matter during initialization of early_mrst_console and might give a warning).

Comment: Agree. Given the code you provided so far, `write` must be declared as a pointer-to-function which takes more than 3 arguments.

Comment: The definition of `struct console` is given at the code snippet at the bottom of my post.  Its write function (which I also gave in the post) has exactly three parameters, as you can see in the first code snippet.

Comment: That's the declaration of `early_mrst_console`, not the definition of `struct console`.

Comment: https://github.com/zen-kernel/zen-kernel/blob/3.15/master/include/linux/console.h defines `struct console`, it contains: `void (*write)(struct console *, const char *, unsigned, unsigned int);`.  This is one more argument than the equivalent file in the linux kernel. You'll have to ask someone working on Zen why that is.